# Setup the bootstrap alert box width

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, width, alert

I am calling bootstrap.alert box from my cshtml (asp.net mvc) and passing it a string that is actually a table with header and a row of data. The issue is that the row length is long due to many columns and when the alert is displayed the content passed out from the dialog. These can be viewed using keyboard <- button that scroll the dialog and content are visible. My query is why not dialog box width is increased based on content or at least a scrollbar is displayed inside the alert box so that user can scroll and see the content. Any idea.
The code is simple like below

```
var tblRowDiv = "<div class='row'><table class='table table-bordered input-block-level'><thead><tr><th>" + ...."</td></tr></tbody></table></div>";

string rMsg = "'" + (((@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(tblRowDiv))+ "'";

<a onclick="bootbox.alert(@rMsg);">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TEST) </a>;
```

The screenshot for issue is like below:
[image: content are running out in bootstrap alert]

This is setup to call on some event to show. Can a scrollbar be added instead? or atleast the dialog size will set to maximum without any specific css for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for your css

```
.modal-dialog { width: 100%; }
.modal-body {overflow-x: scroll;}
```

Comment: I tried the above but it didnt change anything in view.

Comment: I did add the second line as well but the output is still not differ from initial one.

Comment: I did some changes as the my css file over top of other css files like below...adding answer as the content are not fit in this comment.

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes as the my css file over top of other css files like below "

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/my_table.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MyOtherTable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/dataTables.scroller.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I added your two lines in my existing css file my_table.css and found no difference as stated above. Finally I created another css file with just the two lines above and added it in the last of above and viola, it worked..

Thanks Mindeater.